Construct an NPDA for the language where the number of a's <= 3 times the number of b's
I am trying to construct an NPDA for $L = \{\omega \in \{a,b\}^* | n_a(\omega) \le 3 \times n_b(\omega)\}$. This means that for every $b$ there can be at most $3$ $a$'s
So far, I understand that for each $b$, I should pop $1$, $2$, or $3$ $a$'s. But I'm not sure how to translate that into transitions and draw a diagram. I need help.

Construct an NPDA for $L' = \{\omega \in \{a,b\}^* | n_a(\omega) = 3 \times n_b(\omega)\}$. Then try adding appropriate non-determinism for the inequality case.
Alternatively, try writing a CFG for the language and then follow the CFG to NPDA construction procedure.
